# An integral inequality for a real-valued differentiable monotone function on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, integral-inequality, monotone-functions

I have the following question from a past analysis qualifying exam:

> Let $f$ be a real-valued differentiable monotone function on $[0,1]$. Define
>   $$g(x)=\frac12[f(x)+f(1-x)]$$ for $0\le x\le1$. Show that
>   $$\sigma^2(g)\le\frac12\sigma^2(f)$$ where
>   $$\sigma^2(u)=\int_0^1(u(x)-E(u))^2\;dx$$ and
>   $E(u)=\int_0^1u(x)\;dx.$

I'm not really sure where to begin so I wrote out $\sigma^2(g)$ to try to get an idea of what to do here. 
$$\sigma^2(g)=\int_0^1\left(g(x)-\int_0^1g(t)\;dt\right)^2\;dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\left[\frac12(f(x)+f(1-x))-\frac12\int_0^1(f(t)+f(1-t))\;dt\right]^2\;dx$$
$$=\frac14\left(\int_0^1\left[f(x)+f(1-x)-\int_0^1(f(t)+f(1-t))\;dt\right]^2\;dx\right)$$
$$=\frac14\left(\int_0^1\left[f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)\;dt+f(1-x)-\int_0^1f(1-t)\;dt\right]^2\;dx\right)$$
$$=\frac14\left(\int_0^1\left[f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)\;dt\right]^2\;dx+\int_0^1\left[f(1-x)-\int_0^1f(1-t)\;dt\right]^2\;dx-2\int_0^1\left(f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)\;dt\right)\left(f(1-x)-\int_0^1f(1-t)\;dt\right)\;dx\right)$$

I've also noticed that by a change of variables, $\int_0^1f(1-t)\;dt=\int_0^1f(t)\;dt$, but I'm not sure if this will be useful. Additionally, I haven't used the fact that $f$ is differentiable or monotone yet.

Perhaps there is some way to rewrite the integrand so that Cauchy-Schwarz can be applied? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We may assume without loss of generality that $f$ has mean zero. Then we just have to prove that

$$\sigma^2(g)=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2+2 f(x)f(1-x)\,dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx =\sigma^2(f)$$
i.e.
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) f(1-x)\,dx \leq 0. $$
Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$. Our assumption gives $F(0)=F(1)=0$, and as the antiderivative of a decreasing and differentiable function, $F$ is concave. By integration by parts
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}f(x)f(1-x)\,dx &=& \left[F(x)f(1-x)\right]_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}F(x)f'(1-x)\,dx\\ &=& \int_{0}^{1}F(x)f'(1-x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*} $$
where the concavity of $F(x)$ ensures $F(x)\geq 0$ and the monotonicity of $f(x)$ ensures $f'(1-x)\leq 0$.